# how to convert string to date and verify that date comes after a given particular date

Tags: java

I have a string

```
String date1="11/11/2019";
Date date2="Fri Oct 11 17:28:07 IST 2019";
```

I want to know whether date2 comes after date1.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself, perhaps you have some code to show us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String date1Str = "11/11/2019";// assuming it is in dd/MM/yyyy format
        String date2Str = "Fri Oct 11 17:28:07 IST 2019";

        Date date1 = null, date2 = null;
        try {
            date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date1Str);
            date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(date2Str);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (date1 != null && date2 != null) {
            if (date1.compareTo(date2) > 0)
                System.out.println(date1Str + " comes after " + date2Str);
            else if (date1.compareTo(date2) == 0)
                System.out.println(date2Str + " comes after " + date1Str);
            else
                System.out.println(date1Str + " and " + date2Str+" fall on the same date & time");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if date1 comes out of try block. it will not be null.? because of the scope.?

Comment: That is why there is a null check if (date1 != null && date2 != null)  before performing the compareTo operation on it.

Comment: Why are you using old classes like SimpleDateFormat when newer and better ones exists in Java8 an onward for date and time handling?